# elasticsearch sub-aggregation on different index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two indexes, `tweets` and `hashtags`

I'm performing an aggregation on `tweets` to surface the most frequently used hashtags. Straightforward.

Within `hashtags` i am storing a list of hashtags, each with a property representing a "favorited" count.

I want to perform the aggregation on `tweets`, and then for the returned list of hashtags, look them up in `hashtags` index and retrieve `favorite_count`. I'd like to do this all within the same query.

I'm willing to store `hashtags` and `favorite_count` differently if it gets the job done.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I'd be more inclined in suggesting to put the hastags and whatever favorite_count is inside tweets, in a `nested` field. It does sound like multiple data spread replicated multiple times and it is, but this is the kind of data Elasticsearch is happy to work with. The other type - SQL-like one, like you have (an inner join basically) - is not the Elasticsearch way.

Comment: Is this what i should be reading about then? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/mapping-nested-type.html I need to understand the cost of such operation across 1K+ tweets. Coming from a SQL background, i understand ES handles updates quite a bit differently -- like sometimes it doesn't update the original but creates a new document. Thx for the response.